# How do I know if this function is linear or not.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

1)$ T:\mathbb R^2->\mathbb R^2 $ with $T(x,y)=(2x+y,y-2x)$.

Here is the actual question 3(a): Also if you could help me out with question (3b) and (3d.)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2f58E3seHhRcWd6Tk0yQ0hrVFU.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For future reference you may want to learn about posting [mathematical notation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) using $\LaTeX$ and `MathJax`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed. It is a linear function. Let us write your function in vector form first, which means that $T(x,y)=T(v)$, in which $v=(x,y)$

Proof: consider $T(\alpha v+\beta u)$, in which $v=(x_1,y_1)$, $u=(x_2,y_2)$, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

$T(\alpha v+\beta u)=T(\alpha x_1+\beta x_2,\alpha y_1+\beta y_2)=(2\alpha x_1+2\beta x_2+\alpha y_1+\beta y_2,\alpha y_1+\beta y_2-2\alpha x_1-2\beta x_2)=(2\alpha x_1+\alpha y_1,\alpha y_1-2\alpha x_1)+(2\beta x_2+\beta y_2,\beta y_2-2\beta x_2)=\alpha(2x_1+y_1,y_1−2x_1)+\beta(2x_2+y_2,y_2−2x_2)=\alpha T(v)+\beta T(u)$. This is the proof of linearity.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Hey your answer helped me out alot. I was wondering if you could also help me with 3b and 3d since it is R^{2} and R^{3}.

Comment: @user7112108 Please repeat my steps and try $T(\alpha v+\beta u)$ to see if the result is equal to $\alpha T(v)+\beta T(u)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. If one has
$$
T(x,y)=(2x+y,y-2x)
$$ what do you obtain for
$$
T\left[a\times(x_1,y_1)+b\times (x_2,y_2)\right]\:?
$$

Comment: So the answer would be T[ax1,ay1] + [bx2,by2]. So can you explain why would it be linear. My lecturer told me to use axioms.

Comment: @user7112108 Sure. The answer is $a\times T(x_1,y_1)+b\times T(x_2,y_2)$ which is generally the (second) definition of a linear function over $\mathbb{R}^2$. The first definition would be $T\left[(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)\right]=T(x_1,y_1)+T(x_2,y_2)$, $T\left[c \times (x_1,y_1)\right]=c \times T(x_1,y_1)$.

Comment: So would that be the proof for the question (2x+y,y−2x)?

Answer (score 0):

A function in many variables is linear if $f(t\textbf{x}) = t^nf(\textbf{x})$ for some $n\in \Bbb{Z}$.

Here $f(tx,ty)=t\times f(x,y)$. Hence f is linear.